# How to search for every "the" given a .txt file

Tags: python, function, loops, search

How can I create a loop so that it would search every "the" in a .txt file, then capitalize it?? I fully get the capitalizing part, but I am having trouble with searching every "the" in a file.

My strategy was to check `if index[x] == "the"` and do `x += 1` at the end of a loop, but the problem with that was that int. objects are not subscriptable.

How can I create a loop so othat it would search for every instance of a specific word than capitalize it??

```
fr = open('file.txt', 'r')
text = fr.read()

for index in range(len(text)):
    if "the" in index:
        text[index] = text[index].upper()
print(text)
```

Comment: `if "the" in index`? `index` is a number. May be are you trying to do is `text = fr.readlines()` then you can do `for line in text:if 'the' in line:`

Comment: Setting aside that there are much better ways to do this, in your approach `index` is an integer that changes between 0 and `len(text)`. `if "the" in index` translates (on the first iteration) to `if "the" in 0`, which is nonsense (and likely raises an error).

Comment: ``text.replace("the", "THE")`` ?

Comment: @GPhilo Oh, now I get why the code didn't work... thanks for the help!! :)

Comment: @deadshot I'll try that out right now, thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Sushanth I'll try that out right now, thanks for your comment! :)

Comment: Just beware that all the solutions proposed in comments and answers will result in `other` being replaced with `oTHEr`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @Nick true... I just changed the "the" to "the " because sentences never end with 'the.' Thanks for the reminder!! :)

Comment: @Protein you will still have issues with words like `bathe`

Comment: @Nick Right. I'll have to change it to " the ". That actually looks great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
word = 'the'
with open('file.txt') as f_input:
    text = f_input.read()

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    text = text.replace(word, word.upper())

    f_output.write(text)
```

Comment: Oh this works perfectly. Thanks for the help! I didn't know about the text.replace thing, but that seems really useful. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

I see that you already have view on solution, but few things can be observed in your question:

1. Understanding of range - when you do `for index in range(len(text)):`, you actually iterate on numbers from 0 to length of your file content. This is why you have "Int object not subscriptable".
2. When you try to iterate on file content, strings are actually treated as list of characters. So if you do:

```py
for index in "My sentence with the words":
    [...]
```

index will be "M", "y", " " ... and so on in next iterations.

3. You should use `with open(filename) as f:` to prevent from having badly closed file handler.

Some sample output without using text.replace() as mentioned in comments:

```py
with open('file.txt', 'r') as fr:
    text = fr.read()

    arr = text.split(' ')
    new_arr = []

    for index in arr:
        if "the" == index:
            new_arr.append(index.upper())
        else:
            new_arr.append(index)
    output_txt = ' '.join(new_arr)
    print(output_txt)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! :) I think I now fully get how the code works after reading this.

Comment: Nice to hear that - if you found it interesting, please upvote it :)

Comment: I already did but I have less than 15 reputation so my vote won't change the displayed score, but rather be recorded. Thanks again though!! :)